# $\pi/2=\lim_{y\to{\infty}}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 1/ (k(k-1)/y + y/k)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

Algebraic errors over a long period edited multiple times within this body (original post) but basically no major edits although edits critically important.

Main Result:

$\pi/2=\lim_{y\to{\infty}}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 1/ (k(k-1)/y + y/k)$.

Givens:

$\phi^{(m)}(z) = (-1)^{(m+1)}m!\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}1/{(z+k)}^{(m
+1)}$,

and,

$\phi^{(0)}(z+1) = -\alpha + \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}[z/{(k(k +z))}]$.

Derived from givens:

$\phi^{(0)}(z) = (-1)\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}[1/{(z+k)}]$.

$\phi^{(0)}(z+1) = (-1)\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}[1/{(z+1+k)}]$.

$\phi^{(0)}(1) = (-1)\zeta(1)$.

Data:

$y=1E+100$ (to 50 significant digits, keisan online calculator)

$ 2\Phi_0(1/2+iy) =$

$4.6051701859880913680359829093687284152022029772575(E+2) +$

$3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751(E+0)i$

$\pi =  3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751$.

The assumption is,

$ \Im[\phi^{(0)}(1/2+iy)] = \pi/2$ when y is sufficiently large.

Derivation of results.

$\Im[\phi^{(0)}(1/2+iy)] = \pi/2$ when y is sufficiently large,

and therefore,

$\pi/2=\lim_{y\to{\infty}}\Im[\phi^{(0)}(1/2+iy)] = \pi/2$.

Let $z+1 = 1/2 + iy$.

Darn, $z = -1/2 + iy$ corrections follow.

Recall,

$\phi^{(0)}(z+1) = -\alpha + \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}z/{(k(k +z))}$.

Therefore,

$\phi^{(0)}(1/2 + iy) = -\alpha + \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}[(-1/2 + iy)/{(k(-1/2 + iy + k))}]$.

Taking the imaginary part yields,

$\pi/2= \lim_{y\to\infty}\Im[\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}(-1/2 + iy)/{(k(-1/2 + iy + k))}]$.

$\pi/2=\lim_{y\to\infty}\Im[\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} (-1/2 + iy)/(k(k - 1/2 + iy))]$.

Multiplying numerator and denominator by  $(k - 1/2 - iy)$ yields,

$\pi/2 =\lim_{y\to\infty}\Im[\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} (-1/2 + iy)(k - 1/2 - iy)/(k((k-1/2)^2 + y^2))]$.

Removing the real part yields,

$\pi/2=\lim_{y\to\infty}\Im[\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}((iy)(k- 1/2) + iy/2)/(k((k-1/2)^2 + y^2))]$.

$\pi/2=\lim_{y\to\infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}(ky)/(k(k-1/2)^2 + y^2)$.

Rearranging,

$\pi/2=\lim_{y\to\infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}1/ (k(k-1)/y + 1/(4y)) + y/k)$.

The term $1/(4y)$ drops out and,

$\pi/2=\lim_{y\to\infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}1/ (k(k-1)/y + y/k)$.

$\pi/2=\lim_{y\to\infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}k/ (k^2(k-1)/y + y)$.

Comment: Any chance you could link that to the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x^2}$? (very hazy thought; also, couldn't muster the courage to go through what you wrote after the second horizontal line)

Comment: Be courageous and welcome to edit.

Comment: Please and thank you.

Comment: I did a moderately massive edit.

Comment: Thanks, marty et. al., and all those to follow. Thank you. So, what's up with this?

Comment: Perhaps some more common notations? $$\sum_{k=1\to\infty}\iff\sum_{k=1}^\infty\iff\sum_{1\le k<\infty}\iff\sum_{1\le k}$$

Comment: For $y = 536\,870\,911$, I got $\left(\,\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\cdots\,\right)/(\pi/2) = 625.65$. Indeed, it always increases when $y$ is increased.

Answer (score 6):

Setting $\delta=1/y$. Then setting $x=n\delta$, we get that $n(n-1)\delta^2=x(x-\delta)$
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{y\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n(n-1)/y+y}
&=\lim_{\delta\to0}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n(n-1)\delta^2+1}\,\delta\\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac1{x^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}x\\[6pt]
&=\frac\pi2
\end{align}
$$
Since
$$
\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2\delta^2+1}\,\delta}_{\substack{\text{lower Riemann Sum for}\\\int_0^\infty\frac1{x^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}x}}
\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n(n-1)\delta^2+1}\,\delta
\le\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(n-1)^2\delta^2+1}\,\delta}_{\substack{\text{upper Riemann Sum for}\\\int_0^\infty\frac1{x^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}x}}
$$

Comment: right idea, but there seems to be an error in your derivation?

Comment: maybe not, thanks. is that sum the definition of that integral? lost.

Comment: there seems to be a phantom -1/x term w/out a dx in the denominator.

Comment: Setting $\delta=1/y$. Then setting $x=(n-1/2)\delta$, we get that $(n-1/2)\delta^2=x^2$
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{y\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(n-1/2)^2/y+y}
&=\lim_{\delta\to0}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(n-1/2)^2\delta^2+1}\,\delta\\
&=\lim_{\delta\to0}\sum_{m=1/2}^\infty\frac1{(m)^2\delta^2+1}\,\delta\\&=?\int_{0^\infty}\frac1{x^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac\pi2
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Sorry,$\delta = 1/y$, $x = (n-1/2)\delta$, \begin{align} \lim_{y\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(n-1/2)^2/y+y} &=\lim_{\delta\to0}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(n-1/2)^2\delta^2+1}\,\delta\\ =?\int_0‌​^\infty\frac1{x^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}x &=\frac\pi2 \end{align}

Comment: shoot! you may get the idea, however.

Comment: The sum is a Riemann Sum for the integral. $n\delta=x$ and $\delta=\mathrm{d}x$. $\frac1{x(x-\delta)+1}\to\frac1{x^2+1}$

Comment: Thanks. Will research Riemann integrals.

Comment: Look up [Riemann Sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum) rather than Riemann Integral for this answer.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you very much. It has now been proved, again most likely, that Im[lim_{y->oo}digamma(1/2+iy)] = pi/2. Would like to add, Im[digamma(1/2 + 10i)] ~ pi/2 with 27 significant digits.

Comment: @ALL. Edited and corrected. If you interested then click here to see more: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/gufiannfhwgkvps/AAB_REb_EMir9-6468sSUyZfa?dl=0

Comment: Apology, wrong link, corrected, if interested in more: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/c6feaogrtmiggd8/AACvVc1WCz5h_x1YnOJciHK6a?dl=0

Comment: For $y = 536\,870\,911$, I got ( numerically ) $\left(\,\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\cdots\,\right)/(\pi/2) = 625.65$. Indeed, it always increases when $y$ is increased.

Comment: My code:
\begin{align}
&\texttt{Clear[k, y];
y = 536870911;}
\\ &\
\texttt{NSum[1/(k^2/y + k/y + y/k), {k, 1, Infinity}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 100]/(Pi/2)}
\\ = &\ \color{#f00}{625.65\ldots}
\end{align}

Comment: @FelixMarin: Are you sure that no numerical error crept in?  I tried with that $y$ and got $1.570796$.

Comment: Isn't the $\texttt{y/k}$ supposed to be $\texttt{y}$ and the $\texttt{+k/y}$ supposed to be $\texttt{-k/y}$?

Comment: Maybe, my $\texttt{Mathematica}$ version is $\underline{too\ old}$: $\color{#f00}{10.0.0.0}$. This month I'll be in Miami and I'll try to change that.

Comment: edits to OP made correct result now.